# Calling function with two template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I am having a problem calling a template function with two template arguments.

I have a class and the class accepts objects of two different types. I don't know the types yet, so I left them as template parameters. I then store the objects in wrapper classes. In the end I want to be able to call a templated function with two template arguments, that takes my two objects. But I am perplexed at how to do this.

Here is a stripped down version of the code to explain my problem.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
void someTemplateFunction(A a, B b);


class Problem
{
  private:
    class WrapperA
    {
      public:
        virtual void doSomething() = 0;
    };

    template<typename A>
    class ConcreteWrapperA : public wrapperA
    {
      private:
        A a;
      public:
        ConcreteWrapperB(A b_) : a(a_) {}
        virtual void doSomething();
    };

    class WrapperB
    {
      public:
        virtual void doSomething() = 0;
    };

    template<typename B>
    class ConcreteWrapperB : public wrapperB
    {
      private:
        B b;
      public:
        ConcreteWrapperB(B b_) : b(b_) {}
        virtual void doSomething();
    };

    WrapperA *a;
    WrapperB *b;

  public:

    template<typename A>
    void setA(A a)
    {
      a = new ConcreteWrapperA<A>(a);
    }

    template<typename B>
    void setB(B b)
    {
      a = new ConcreteWrapperB<B>(b);
    }

    void call_someTemplateFunction(); // ??????? How do i do this?
};
```

Comment: Is every `A` or `B` types known? I mean, e.g., that you know that `B` can be `int, long or short` and nothing more. If yes, then I can provide an answer. On the other hand if you can set both with one function, then of course use 1st answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the types of `A` and `B` are not know. I though about using `boost::variant` together with visitors. But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: boost::variant requires that all possible types are known before using boost::variant. It is exactly what I asked before. Sorry for asking twice the same question, maybe my previous Q was not clear: Do you know all possible types which can be used for calling either `Problem::setA` or `Problem::setB`?

Comment: The possible types of `A` and `B` are not known. I am developing a library and I don't know in advance what concrete types the user will pass as `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've type-erased both types `A` and `B` separately, so there's nowhere in the translation of your code that both types `A` and `B` are known.

If you can write a single function `template<typename A, typename B> void set(A, B)` then you could capture the pair type `<A, B>` at that point.

Alternatively, would it be possible for `someTemplateFunction` to operate without knowing both types `A` and `B` at the same time?

---

This is an issue fundamental to the design of C++ as a single-pass, separate compilation language.

Suppose that your program has three compilation units; `A.cpp` calls `setA` with a range of types `T[A]`, `B.cpp` calls `setB` with another range of types `T[B]`, and `C.cpp` owns the `Problem` object and wants to call `someTemplateFunction`.  Then there's no time during compilation when the compiler knows both the range of types in `A.cpp` *and* the range of types in `B.cpp`, so it can't instantiate `someTemplateFunction` with the appropriate cross-product `T[A] x T[B]`.

Comment: I think, I understand your answer. In practice I could probably know both types `A` and `B` at the same time, but I wanted to be able to add multiple objects of `B` and maybe store them in a list without having to always pass `A` as well.